# How can I insert multiple values into json files?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm building a bash script that needs to send a json payload to an API.  The payload below is stored in `payload.json`, will be used all the time and is in the same path as the script.  The `""` values are what I need to populate with variables from within the same script.

```
{
    "appId": "",
    "appName": "",
    "authType": "OIDC",
    "authSettings": {
      "applicationType": "SERVICE",
      "clientAuthenticationType": "CLIENT_SECRET",
      "grantTypes": [
        "CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"
      ],
      "groups": [
        ""
      ],
      "responseTypes": [
        "TOKEN"
      ],
      "inclusion": [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
      ],
      "tokenValidity": {
        "accessTokenLifetimeMinutes": 60,
        "refreshTokenLifetimeMinutes": 10080,
        "refreshTokenWindowMinutes": 1440
      }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this correctly.

How can I pass single values to `.appId`, `.appName` and multiple values to `.groups[]`, `.inclusion[]` all at the same time?

I started on this path for each variable but got nowhere:

```
appId=31337
jq '.appId = "${appId}"' config.json > tempfile.json
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do other variables look like?

Comment: Have a look at the `--arg` and `--args` options when [invoking jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use some "nested" jq calls:

```bash
appId=1234
appName="My App"
groups=(g1 g2 g3)
inclusion=(i1 i2 i3 i4 i5)

jq --arg appId "$appId"\
   --arg appName "$appName" \
   --argjson groups "$(jq -n --args '$ARGS.positional' "${groups[@]}")" \
   --argjson inclusion "$(jq -n --args '$ARGS.positional' "${inclusion[@]}")" \
   ' .appId = $appId
     | .appName = $appName
     | .authSettings.groups = $groups
     | .authSettings.inclusion = $inclusion
  ' template.json
```

If the appId should be a number in the resulting JSON, use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`

Comment: Additionally, I have a requirement to be able to append (not overwrite) to `groups` and `inclusion` which I achieved with:
`.authSettings.groups = .authSettings.groups + $groups` and `.authSettings.inclusion = .authSettings.inclusion + $inclusion`

Comment: Or, use the `+=` operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`--arg` and `--argjson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) with null input, e.g.

```
jq -n --arg id "$appid" --arg name "$appname" \
  --argjson groups '["your", "groups", "here"]' \
'{
    "appId": $id,
    "appName": $name,
    "authType": "OIDC",
    "authSettings": {
      "applicationType": "SERVICE",
      "clientAuthenticationType": "CLIENT_SECRET",
      "grantTypes": [
        "CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"
      ],
      "groups": $groups,
      "responseTypes": [
        "TOKEN"
      ],
      "inclusion": [
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
      ],
      "tokenValidity": {
        "accessTokenLifetimeMinutes": 60,
        "refreshTokenLifetimeMinutes": 10080,
        "refreshTokenWindowMinutes": 1440
      }
    }
}'
```

---

Or, if you cannot modify the template file to be a jq filter/program, you can load it and then merge it with your custom arguments. Note that you need to match the structure exactly for this to work:

```
jq --arg appId 123 --argjson groups '["your","groups"]' \
  '. * { $appId, authSettings: { $groups } }' template.json
```

Alternatively by assigning each property:

```
jq --arg appId 123 --argjson groups '["your","groups"]' \
  '.appId = $appId | .authSettings.groups = $groups' tpl.json
```